# Swapping alternate nodes of linkedlist

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type LinkedList struct {
    first, last *node   

}

type node struct {
    item int
    next *node

}

func (l *LinkedList) add (val int) {
    n := node {
        item: val,
        next: nil,
    }
    if l.first == nil {
        l.last = &n
        l.first = &n
    } else {
        l.last.next = &n
        l.last = &n
    }   

}

func (l *LinkedList) traverse () {
    for n := l.first; n != nil; n = n.next {
        fmt.Printf("%v ", n.item)

    }

    fmt.Println()

}

func (l *LinkedList) swapLL () {
    if l.first == nil {
        panic("First element cannot be null")
        }

    if l.first.next == nil {
        return
    }

    ptr1 := l.first
    var ptr2 *node
    var ptr3 *node
    var prev *node

    for ; ptr1 != nil && ptr1.next != nil; {
        //Allocate resources
        ptr2 = ptr1.next
        ptr3 = ptr2.next

        //swap
        ptr2.next = ptr1
        ptr1.next = ptr3

        //hook to the previous pair
        if prev == nil {
            l.first = ptr2
        } else {
            prev.next = ptr2
        }

        //advance
        prev = ptr1
        ptr1 = ptr3
    }

}

func main () {
    l := LinkedList {
        first: nil,
        last: nil,
    }

    l.add(10)
    l.add(20)
    l.add(30)
    l.add(40)

    l.traverse()

    l.swapLL()

    l.traverse()
}
```

---

#### Input:

```
Linkedlist:  10 -> 20 -> 30 -> 40 -> null
```

#### Output:

```
Linkedlist: 20 -> 10 -> 40 -> 30 -> null
```

#### Question:

Here 10 and 20 are adjacent thus they were swapped. Likewise, 30 and 40 are adjacent thus they were swapped.

I am looking for suggestions for improving my code, any optimizations, or anything to make my code more readable and elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome!

You may be interested in viewing [the Go API implementation of a linked list](https://golang.org/src/container/list/list.go). Their implementation is not restricted to just integer node data.

### Use `go fmt`

A few of your lines have trailing whitespace. Likewise, some of your formatting isn't standard for Go.

If you run `go fmt` on the source code, it cleans all that up for you.

### Don't unnecessarily export things

Your type `LinkedList` is exported. If this is for a library, you should add a comment explaining it's usage (used to generate documentation: see [Godoc](https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code)). If it's not for a library, it shouldn't be exported.

Going forward, I'll assume it's not meant for a library. Otherwise the fields of `LinkedList` also need to be exported, and the `node` type as well.

### Avoid extra typing when initializing a `struct`

When initializing a `struct`, you don't have to initialize the fields to values that would already be the default.

See [§Composite Literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) in the language specification for more details.

```
n := node{
    item: val,
    next: nil,
}
```

Can be written as:

```
n := node{
    item: val,
}
```

And

```
l := linkedList{
    first: nil,
    last:  nil,
}
```

Becomes

```
l := linkedList{}
```

### Combine variable declarations:

We [can combine](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) multiple variable declarations under one `var` keyword.

```
var ptr2 *node
var ptr3 *node
var prev *node
```

Becomes either

```
var ptr2, ptr3, prev *node
```

Or

```
var (
    ptr2 *node
    ptr3 *node
    prev *node
)
```

I prefer the shorter notation most times when the variables are of the same type, but either is better.

### Use the specific `Printf` verb

You use the `%v` verb, but here we know at compile time that we're printing integers. You can safely use `%d` instead.

### Return an `error` instead of `panic()`ing

Unless you expect to always `recover()` from the `panic()`, you should return an `error` value instead. This is more common.

```
func (l *linkedList) swapLL() {
    if l.first == nil {
        panic("First element cannot be null")
    }

    if l.first.next == nil {
        return
    }

    //...
}
```

Becomes

```
func (l *linkedList) swapLL() error {
    if l.first == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("List cannot be empty")
    }

    if l.first.next == nil {
        return nil
    }

    //...

    return nil
}
```

This now makes it easy to check for the error:

```
if err := l.swapLL(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

### Conclusion

Here is the final source I ended up with.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type linkedList struct {
    first, last *node
}

type node struct {
    item int
    next *node
}

func (l *linkedList) add(val int) {
    n := node{
        item: val,
    }

    if l.first == nil {
        l.last = &n
        l.first = &n
    } else {
        l.last.next = &n
        l.last = &n
    }
}

func (l *linkedList) traverse() {
    for n := l.first; n != nil; n = n.next {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", n.item)
    }

    fmt.Println()
}

func (l *linkedList) swapLL() error {
    if l.first == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("List cannot be empty")
    }

    if l.first.next == nil {
        return nil
    }

    ptr1 := l.first

    var ptr2, ptr3, prev *node

    for ptr1 != nil && ptr1.next != nil {
        //Allocate resources
        ptr2 = ptr1.next
        ptr3 = ptr2.next

        //swap
        ptr2.next = ptr1
        ptr1.next = ptr3

        //hook to the previous pair
        if prev == nil {
            l.first = ptr2
        } else {
            prev.next = ptr2
        }

        //advance
        prev = ptr1
        ptr1 = ptr3
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    l := linkedList{}

    l.add(10)
    l.add(20)
    l.add(30)
    l.add(40)

    l.traverse()

    if err := l.swapLL(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    l.traverse()
}
```

Hope this helps!